# How can I blend between my UIView and my EAGLView?

Tags: iphone, opengl, uikit, uiview, eaglview

I have an opengl scene rendering on an EAGLView layer and some other elements (circles and such) rendering on a UIView (which is a sibling of the EAGLView, positioned above it).  Is it possible to blend colors between the two layers?  I'd like to do some difference blending to get an inversion effect on the colors from EAGLView.

I've been playing around with CGBlendMode but it only seems to affect what I'm drawing in that current view.  I think this has something to do with the CGContext but I'm a little hazy on the details, can I force the UIView and the EAGLView to have the same CGContext so that the blending works between them?

Help, corrections, clarifications are all appreciated.  Thanks in advance,
-S

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer is you can not. Long answer follows.

By `EAGLView` you must mean the subclass of `UIView` that is included in the OpenGL ES Template in Xcode. What makes this class special is that the `layerClass` class method is overridden and return the `CAEAGLLayer` class instead of the `CALayer` class, as is default.

`UIView` and `CALayer` work in pairs. All `UIView` objects are backed by a `CALayer`, the `CALayer` is the object responsible for layout and rendering to screen. The `UIView` is a delegate to the `CALayer`, and is responsible for drawing it's graphics when needed.

`CALayer` will let it's delegate (the `UIView`) draw into a `CGContextRef`. It is one context per `UIView`, so you can not use `CGBlendMode` to blend several views since it will only function within one single UIView context.

Blending of `CALayer` should be done using the filter properties. These are defined for iPhone OS but the available filters are *undefined* according to the documentation. This is because Core Image is not available on iPhone OS at this time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll be able to blend colours in that sense. The best you can do is have one completely obscuring the other, or have the top layer semi-transparent (in which case, you'll see the part underneath) - but you won't be able to do XOR type drawing.